# How can I remove a cell's background color? (how can I customize it)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Let's say I want to make the cell have a color or make the borders of the cells more rounded or remove the line between the first cell and the second, how would I do that in SwiftUI?

[image]

```
struct TestView: View {
    init() {
            UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
            UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
        UITableViewCell.appearance()}
        var body: some View {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
                .overlay(
                    List {
                        Group {
                            Text("Hallo")
                            Text("World")
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(50)
                    
            )
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried the following?:  .listRowBackground(Color.clear) - also, it looks like your title asks one question, but you pose a few other questions in the body of the question. What is the desired outcome?

Comment: Thanks a lot! now I'm trying to remove the lines in the cell.

I tried adding .onAppear {
                            UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
                        }
but it doesn't seem to work, any suggestions?

Comment: There is an easy way to do it if you are developing for iOS 15. You can use the following: .listRowSeparator(.hidden) --- but if you are not using iOS 15, it gets a bit more complicated. I have tried a few solutions on my end but they are messy and involve embedding the list in a LazyVStack.

Comment: It doesn't appear on my end for some reason but thanks! (feel free to add your comment as an answer so you can get some points)

Comment: I believe it only appears if you are using Xcode beta. If interested, you can download here - https://developer.apple.com/xcode/resources/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `.listRowBackground` to your list:

```
struct TestView: View {
init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
    UITableViewCell.appearance()}
    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            .overlay(
                List {
                    Group {
                        Text("Hallo")
                        Text("World")
                    }.listRowBackground(Color.clear) //Add here
                }.padding(50)
                
                
                
        )
    }
```

Comment: Just put the .listRowBackground in the previous bracket